# MyTezosBaker Efficiency

Tags: efficiency, mytezosbaker

[MyTezosBaker](https://mytezosbaker.com/) has an efficiency column. I assume this is a measure of if a baker is online for baking and endorsing events, though I'm not really sure.

How is efficiency calculated? Can this be devined from https://tzscan.io?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to calculate efficiency and the one currently used by that site is the following formula:

(bakes + endorses) divided by (priority 0 bakes rights + endorse rights)

Using that formula you can actually get a greater than 100% efficiency when you bake a non priority 0 block.

For added complexity, you can decide to weigh the value differently depending on age of blocks baked because it might be more meaningful to you to know that a baker has been doing a better job very recently rather than over a long period of time. Additionally you might want to value bakes as more important than endorses.

The data to perform these calculations yourself is available at https://tzscan.io/

Comment: The window filtering is a great idea!

Comment: Great, thank you! Bakes and enorsements are obvious on tzscan.io. Is there an easy way to see rights per baker?

Comment: The rights on tzscan are found under the "Bakings" tab for an account. If you scroll down and look at the history section it actually lists also the upcoming cycles for both bakes and endorsements where you can click the arrow to expand the details to see the priorities and slots. Here is a link to an example for one of the foundation baker accounts https://tzscan.io/tz3bvNMQ95vfAYtG8193ymshqjSvmxiCUuR5?default=baking